# How can I choose which icon based on a variable?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

My leaflet.js code defines various icons:

```
var blueIcon = new largeIcon({iconUrl: 'blue.png'});
var redIcon = new largeIcon({iconUrl: 'red.png'});
var orangeIcon = new largeIcon({iconUrl: 'orange.png'});
```

so that I can then use one of them later:

```
marker = new L.Marker(latlng, {icon: redIcon, draggable: true});
```

However, I want to choose the icon based on a variable which is set from outside the .js file:

```
var useIcon = 'blueIcon';
```

**How can I change the `marker = ...` line so that it creates the object defined by useIcon rather than hard-coding redIcon?** icon: expects an object rather than a string.

Comment: Put your icons in an object, then use bracket notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of declaring separate variables, group them up in an object: (This is sometimes called a dictionary)

```
var iconList = {
    blueIcon: new largeIcon({iconUrl: 'blue.png'}),
    redIcon: ...,
    ...
};
```

Then you can select the one you want with:

```
marker = new L.Marker(latlng, {icon: iconList[useIcon], draggable: true});
```